# Why is scala list class named ::

Tags: list, scala

Why is the scala list implementation named :: and not a class name? Is there some special meaning behind that?

Comment: Basically, it was inspired by Haskell's "cons" operator (`:`), but the creators of Scala chose to use `:` for type ascription, so they designated `::` as "cons" instead. In Haskell `::` happens to denote type ascription, so the meanings of `:` and `::` in Scala are exactly swapped with respect to their meanings in Haskell.

Comment: ML and OCaml have had :: for cons list and : for type ascription for a very long time. I would say it is Haskell that departed from that. As scala needs much more type ascription for languages with Hindley Milner type inference (routine parameters) it made sense to choose it this way

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is to work with pattern matching. You have something called an *Infix Operator Patterns* where pattern `p op q` is equivalent to the constructor or extractor pattern `op(p, q)`.

So the case class `::` defines the constructor `::(head, tail)`. That allows you to match like this:

```
list match {
  case ::(head, tail) =>
}
```

But with the infix operator pattern, you can write the more familiar syntax:

```
list match {
  case head :: tail =>
}
```

Note that a stackoverflow search on ["[scala] infix operator pattern"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscala%5D%20infix%20operator%20pattern) returns similar questions and additional use cases of the pattern.

Comment: Note that Daniel's mention about the trailing colon making it right associative is also relevant as `case 1 :: 2 :: Nil` will then be equivalent to `case ::(1, ::(2, Nil))`. Section 8.1.10 of http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf explains this in more details and provides further references.

Answer (score 22):

A linked list is composed of two cases: a cons cell (with a head and a tail), and the empty list.  These cases are called `::` and `Nil` respectively in Scala, as in other languages with ML heritage.  In an immutable implementation, the most natural encoding looks something like this:

```
sealed trait List[+A]

case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

This works just fine and there's really nothing wrong with it.  You can define a `::` method on `List` (or `prepend`, if you prefer), and things work exactly as you would expect.  In this case, the "concrete implementation" of `List` will be `Cons`, though technically both `Cons` and `Nil` are concrete implementations.

Here's the problem though: we want to be able to pattern-match on an instance of `List` to get back the contents.  As things stand, that pattern matching would require the following syntax:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
  case Cons(hd, tl) => hd + sum(tl)
  case Nil => 0
}
```

This is a bit ugly though.  What we really want is to be able to use the `::` operator in our pattern matching just the same as we use it when constructing the list originally.  This is why the `Cons` class is named `::`.

By defining a case class of two parameters, we're basically telling Scala that we want it to allow us to use that case class as an infix extractor in pattern matching.  The trailing colon makes that extractor right-associative, giving us the expected syntax:

```
sealed trait List[+A]

case class ::[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]

def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
  case hd :: tl => hd + sum(tl)
  case Nil => 0
}
```

This is why any instance of `List` that has contents will be an instance of class `::`, since that is the non-empty implementation of `List`.

Answer (score 3):

It's the standard name of the cons operator that prepends an element to a list.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the concrete implementation of `List` is called the same as the operator

Comment: @Kim, yes, it is the cons operator, but as Luigi stated (which was my question) - that doesn't explain why the concrete list implementation is called that.